# How do I include a tickbox (formcontrol) in the tables filter?

Tags: excel

I have a table.
I have a row with cells with a tickbox (formcontrol).

When I filter I can't distinguish between ticked and non ticked.

How do I do that?

Comment: You have to link each checkbox to a cell and then filter based on the cell value (TRUE or FALSE). See [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3696-excel-filter-based-on-checkbox.html#:~:text=Filter%20Data%20Using%20Checkbox%20in%20Excel%201%20Right,the%20checkbox%2C%20the%20word%20%22FALSE%20...%20See%20More.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic solution; you can do this by assigning checkbox value to a cell. For example you have a checkbox at A2 cell, select the checkbox (dont check just select with right click) and write "=C2" (or any other column) to formula bar. After that if you check checkbox C3 cell changes to TRUE. If you uncheck, C3 changes to FALSE. Then you can filter C column with True or False, and you can hidden C Column if you want. If you have too much checkbox, you can use a macro to assign the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Problem is that the cell contains other text as well. Well, I could just make the tickbox in another cell and make the true/false white so it cant be seen but it kind of annoys my eyes that the filter is in another column than the tickbox in the table if I do that. Same cell would mean true/fals woul ..... omg I just realized the cells ticked off will have text which I havent filled out yet (think "logged ticket" tickbox and a ticket # in the cell). Well, that solved itself kind of. 

Thank you again!!